# Вещественные типы данных

Tags: c

Дан вещественный тип данных, у которого максимальное значение 10^20, нужно узнать сколько бит в нем отводится под экспоненту. Объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вещественные числа с плавающей точкой, поддержанные на уровне процессора, описаны международным стандартом IEEE 754.

Так основными двумя типами для любых вычислений являются single-precision (одинарной точности) и double-precision (двойной точности) floating-point (числа с плавающей точкой).

Под представление с одинарной точностью выделено 32 бита, под двойную - 64 бита.

В битах в числах одинарной точности:

```
| 1 бит под знак | 8 бит экспоненты | 23 бита мантиссы |
```

Для двойной точности:

```
| 1 бит под знак | 11 бит экспоненты | 52 бита мантиссы |
```

Попробуй [так](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union {
    float f;
    struct {
        unsigned int mantisa : 23;
        unsigned int exponent : 8;
        unsigned int sign : 1;
    } parts;
} float_cast;

int main(void) {
    float_cast d1 = { .f = 0.15625 };
    printf("sign = %x\n", d1.parts.sign);
    printf("exponent = %x\n", d1.parts.exponent);
    printf("mantisa = %x\n", d1.parts.mantisa);
}
```

Comment: А как же 10-байтный long double?

Comment: Это вы говорите о стандартных представлениях. Но у них верхний предел отнюдь не 10^20.

Comment: Я тут посчитать попытался - вроде получилось, но с Long double что-то не то - можешь глянуть?

Answer (score 4):

Формально могут быть разные представления...

Для определенности будем рассматривать [нормализованную форму IEEE 745](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB), когда мантисса принимает значения от 1 до 2, а порядок - со сдвигом в половину размера.

Пусть под порядок отводится b бит; тогда максимальное значение порядка получается как 2<sup>b-1</sup>. Итого Дальше посмотрим - для 7 бит получается 64, максимальное число - 2*2<sup>64</sup> - примерно 3.6*10<sup>19</sup>. Немного не хватает. Значит, 8 бит - правда, при этом будет получаться уже 2*2<sup>128</sup> ~ 6.8*10<sup>38</sup>.

Поэтому у меня ощущение, что от вас ждут ответ 7 бит :)

Однако стоит, например, изменить сдвиг в представлении порядка или представление мантиссы рассматривать не нормализованное - и сразу могут быть и другие варианты.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: А загляни ко мне в ответ - не пойму, почему long double не сходится...

Comment: @Qwertiy Не, меня не хватит, чтоб сразу сказать, что к чему (потому и пишу свое *"По-моему, так"* :)), а разбираться досконально - сейчас времени нет. Ощущение, что long double - тип скользкий, и сколько в нем точно байт - никто и не знает. О! его можно пощупать на значимость - портить по байтику и смотреть... Сейчас глянем...

Comment: @Qwertiy Вот, я тут медленно запарывал `long double` - и первые байты оно никак не реагировало! - см. https://ideone.com/Nhg97d - так что *реально* это 10 байт...

Answer (score 2):

> Дан вещественный тип данных, нужно узнать сколько бит в нем отводится под экспоненту.

Есть интересный способ: известно, что все используемые вещественные числа используют 1 бит под знак, имеют мантиссу и экспоненту. Мы легко можем узнать размер типа через `sizeof`, а с числом бит в мантиссе и экспоненте немного сложнее.

Возьмём число 1 и будем делить его на 2 пока не получится 0. В какой момент он получится? Сначала число будет нормализованным и мантисса будет содержать 0, а экспонента будет уменьшаться. Затем экспонента достигнет минимального значения, число перейдёт в денормализованную форму и всю мантиссу проползёт одна единичка. Когда эта единичка скроется за пределами точности типа, число превратится в 0. Еще стоит заметить, что положительных экспонент на 1 больше, чем отрицательных, что даёт нам +1 бит и возможность безнаказанно считать положительные степени на 1 больше отрицательной.

При попытке это использовать получим такой код: https://ideone.com/YuIWNc

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COUNT(type, result_m, result_e) do { \
  type x = 1, exp; \
  unsigned res, e; \
  for (res=0; x!=0; ++res) x/=2.; \
  for (exp=1,e=0; exp*2<res; ++e) exp*=2; \
  *result_e = e+1; \
  *result_m = res-exp+1; \
} while(0)

int main(void)
{
  unsigned f_m, f_e, d_m, d_e, ld_m, ld_e;

  COUNT(float, &f_m, &f_e);
  COUNT(double, &d_m, &d_e);
  COUNT(long double, &ld_m, &ld_e);

  printf("              S   M   E   SZ\n");
  printf("float:        1  %2u  %2u  %3u\n",  f_m,  f_e, 8 * sizeof(float));
  printf("double:       1  %2u  %2u  %3u\n",  d_m,  d_e, 8 * sizeof(double));
  printf("long double:  1  %2u  %2u  %3u\n", ld_m, ld_e, 8 * sizeof(long double));
}
```

Результат:

```
              S   M   E   SZ
float:        1  23   8   32
double:       1  52  11   64
long double:  1  63  15  128
```

Как видим, размер экспоненты совпадает [с википедией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008): 8, 11 и 15. С размером мантиссы немного сложнее - float и double совпадают (просто 1 бит вынесен в знак), но у long double почему-то получается 64 бита, вместо ожидаемых 113. С другой стороны, насколько я помню, плюсы должны использовать 10 байт для long double, а не 16. Под 10 байт в общем-то подходит, но sizeof показывает 16. Если в коде есть ошибка - пишите в комментариях - поправлю.

Comment: sizeof показывает вместе с выравниванием, разве нет?

Comment: @pavel, какие 4 бита? У всех число байт целое же? Кстати, посмотрел внимательнее, похоже, у меня всё-таки какой-то баг, т. к. 1+63+15=79 - где-то 1 бит потерялся - под 10 байт должно быть 80.

Comment: Вот, я тут медленно запарывал long double - и первые байты оно никак не реагировало! - см. https://ideone.com/Nhg97d - так что **реально** это 10 байт...

Comment: @Harry, так всё равно у меня 1 бит потерялся, даже для 10 байт. И, разве, sizeof не должен возвращать десятку?

Comment: `sizeof` возвращает количество памяти, выделенное переменной данного типа, а уж будет она вся использоваться или нет, и как именно (к вопросу о бите) - это дело компилятора :) Если серьезно - насчет бита не знаю. Не могу уверенно высказаться ни за, ни против вашего способа...

Comment: @Harry, задал отдельным вопросом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/734770/178988