# Потерялся 1 бит в long double

Tags: c++, c, типы-данных, float, хранение-данных

По следам [вопроса о битовом представлении вещественных чисел](/q/734576/178988) и [моего ответа на него](/a/734615/178988).

Хочу программно для любого вещественного типа определить, сколько бит в нём отводится под мантиссу, а сколько под экспоненту. Для этого написал следующий код (в нём бит под знак считается отдельно от мантиссы, поэтому числа на 1 меньше):

https://ideone.com/YuIWNc - код на Си (float, double, long double)
https://ideone.com/342B4S - код на Си++ (float, double, long double)
https://ideone.com/VURQnw - код на Си++ (float, double, long double, __float128)

```
#include <cstdio>

template <typename typed> void count(unsigned *result_m, unsigned *result_e)
{
  typed x = 1, exp;
  unsigned res, e;
  for (res=0; x!=0; ++res) x/=2;
  for (exp=1,e=0; exp*2<res; ++e) exp*=2;
  *result_e = e+1;
  *result_m = res-exp+1;
}

int main(void)
{
  unsigned f_m, f_e, d_m, d_e, ld_m, ld_e, f128_m, f128_e;

  count<float>(&f_m, &f_e);
  count<double>(&d_m, &d_e);
  count<long double>(&ld_m, &ld_e);
  count<__float128>(&f128_m, &f128_e);

  printf("              S    M   E   SZ\n");
  printf("float:        1  %3u  %2u  %3u\n",    f_m,    f_e, 8 * sizeof(float));
  printf("double:       1  %3u  %2u  %3u\n",    d_m,    d_e, 8 * sizeof(double));
  printf("long double:  1  %3u  %2u  %3u\n",   ld_m,   ld_e, 8 * sizeof(long double));
  printf("__float128:   1  %3u  %2u  %3u\n", f128_m, f128_e, 8 * sizeof(__float128));
}
```

Получается так:

```
              S    M   E   SZ
float:        1   23   8   32
double:       1   52  11   64
long double:  1   63  15  128
__float128:   1  112  15  128
```

Для `float`, `double` и даже `__float128` всё работает ([Википедия, IEEE 754-2008](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008#.D0.9E.D1.81.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.B8_.D0.B2.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD.D1.8F.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D1.84.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D0.B0.D1.82.D1.8B)).
А вот с `long double` возникают проблемы:

1. `1+63+15 = 79` - 79 бит. Вместо 80. **Где ещё один бит?**
2. `long double` представляет собой 10-байтные числа, но `sizeof` вернул 16.
   Как-то можно получить 10?

Comment: @pavel, но у меня нет битовых операций в коде и все действия с большими числами ведутся в самом вещественном типе. 32-битный `unsigned` использован для счётчиков. 64-битных целочисленных переменных в коде нет вообще, битовых операций - тоже (`/=2` и `*=2` делаются над вещественными). Почему я считаю, что так можно, я описал в том ответе (старался описать подробно). Если так по какой-то причине нельзя, то хотелось бы эту причину увидеть ответом.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Один бит потерялся из-за того, что на платформе x86 80-битное плавающее значение имеет одно принципиальное отличие в представлении от 32- и 64-битных IEEE754 плавающих значений (`float` и `double`).

`float` и `double` используют представление с *неявной* ведущей единицей в мантиссе. То есть в нормализованном представлении старшая единица в мантиссе не хранится явно, а лишь подразумевается. А вот в расширенном 80-битном плавающем типе `long double` эта ведущая единица в мантиссе всегда хранится *явно*.

Из-за этого и возникает разница.

Для типов `float` и `double` ваш первый цикл сначала итерирует через нормализованные представления числа, в которых явная мантисса всегда равна нулю, а экспонента уменьшается от половины своего максимального значения (`127` для `float`) до значения `1`:

```
// Для `float`

// Нормализованные представления: мантисса равна 0, а экспонента убывает от 127 до 1

0x3F800000
...
0x00800000  <- после 126 делений
```

После этого ваш цикл продолжает итерировать через денормализованные представления числа, в которых экспонента равна `0`, а по мантиссе вправо движется одинокая единица. Когда эта одинокая единица вылетит за правый край мантиссы, `x` станет равен нулю и цикл завершится

```
// Денормализованные представления: экспонента равна 0, а мантисса состоит
// из движущейся вправо единицы

0x00400000
0x00200000
...
0x00000001
0x00000000  <- после 150 делений
```

Заметьте, в `float` и `double` единица в мантиссе возникает только в самом первом денормализованном значении и проходит через все биты мантиссы. Получается, что количество денормализованных ненулевых значений в этом случае равно количеству битов в мантиссе.

Однако при использовании `long double` единица в старшем бите мантиссы явно присутствовала *всегда*, с самого начала. Когда в вашем цикле экспонента `long double` достигает нуля и цикл начинает подсчитывать денормализованные значения `long double`, единица в мантиссе не возникает "из никуда" в старшую позицию мантиссы (как это было в в `float` и `double`), а уже присутствует в старшей позиции изначально и "стартует" именно оттуда. Из-за этого та часть цикла, которая считает денормализованные значения, делает на одну итерацию меньше.

---

Кстати, странная манера складывать в одну сумму - `res` - половину диапазона экспоненты и ширину мантиссы чревата проблемами. Вы потом вычисляете значение `log2 res` и ожидаете, что эта величина будет правильно описывать количество битов в экспоненте. Однако если в некотором гипотетическом плавающем типе мантисса окажется очень широкой, то величина `log2 res` может оказаться ошибочной.

Comment: Но при этом делается правильное число итераций, т. е. эта постоянная единица сжирает 1 бит, а точность и диапазон от этого не увеличиваются? Или всё-таки увеличиваются?

Comment: _"странная манера складывать в одну сумму - res - половину диапазона экспоненты и ширину мантиссы чревата проблемами"_ - а можно было как-то их разделить? Я как-то не придумал способа. Ну и чтобы вычисление логарифма оказалось неверным, надо чтобы число бит в мантиссе было больше pow(2, число бит в экспоненте) - не думаю, что кому-то нужен такой шикарный тип))

Comment: А на вопросы ответишь?

Answer (score 3):

[Справка по C/C++](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) сообщает удивительную подробность:

> **long double** — тип с плавающей точкой повышенной точности. Не
>   обязательно отображается на типы IEEE-754. Обычно 80-битный тип с
>   плавающей точкой формата x87 на архитектурах x86 и x86-64.

Получается, ответственность за реализацию лежит целиком на компиляторе.

Чтобы проверить, куда и какой бит делся, можно добавить распечатку в процесс "обнаружения" всех бит:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cinttypes>

template <typename typed> void count(unsigned *result_m, unsigned *result_e)
{
  typed x = 1, exp;
  unsigned res, e;
  std::uint32_t bytes[4] {0,0,0,0};
  for (res=0; x!=0; ++res) {
    x/=2;
    std::memcpy(bytes, &x, sizeof(typed));
    printf("x(%3d): %08x %08x %08x %08x\n", res, bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]);
  }
  for (exp=1,e=0; exp*2<res; ++e) exp*=2;
  *result_e = e+1;
  *result_m = res-exp+1;
}

int main(void)
{
  unsigned f_m, f_e, d_m, d_e, ld_m, ld_e;

  count<float>(&f_m, &f_e);
  count<double>(&d_m, &d_e);
  count<long double>(&ld_m, &ld_e);

  printf("              S   M   E   SZ\n");
  printf("float:        1  %2u  %2u  %3u\n",  f_m,  f_e, 8 * sizeof(float));
  printf("double:       1  %2u  %2u  %3u\n",  d_m,  d_e, 8 * sizeof(double));
  printf("long double:  1  %2u  %2u  %3u\n", ld_m, ld_e, 8 * sizeof(long double));
}
```

Так, например, для 32-битного числа:

```
x(  0): 3f000000
x(  1): 3e800000
x(  2): 3e000000
x(  3): 3d800000
...с номера 126 наступает денормализация:
x(124): 01000000
x(125): 00800000
x(126): 00400000
x(127): 00200000
x(128): 00100000
x(129): 00080000
x(130): 00040000
...и далее перебор заканчивается:
x(147): 00000002
x(148): 00000001
x(149): 00000000
```

Где бит пропал - там и заковыка. Аналогично будут видны все незадействованные биты, и так можно оценить эффективный размер типа.

Продолжение для long double:

```
x(    0): 00000000 80000000 00003ffe 00000000
x(    1): 00000000 80000000 00003ffd 00000000
x(    2): 00000000 80000000 00003ffc 00000000
x(    3): 00000000 80000000 00003ffb 00000000
...денормализация:
x(16379): 00000000 80000000 00000003 00000000
x(16380): 00000000 80000000 00000002 00000000
x(16381): 00000000 80000000 00000001 00000000
x(16382): 00000000 40000000 00000000 00000000
x(16383): 00000000 20000000 00000000 00000000
...
x(16410): 00000000 00000004 00000000 00000000
x(16411): 00000000 00000002 00000000 00000000
x(16412): 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000
x(16413): 80000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
x(16414): 40000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
...финал:
x(16443): 00000002 00000000 00000000 00000000
x(16444): 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
x(16445): 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Итак, один бит действительно всегда выставлен в 1 для нормальных чисел, в соответствии с английской википедией на тему [Extended Precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision) - и становится 0 после денормализации. В "стандартных" 32-битных и 64-битных представлениях этот бит [опускается](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B4.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.B8_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.B2_.D0.BF.D0.B0.D0.BC.D1.8F.D1.82.D0.B8)