# long в double C#

Tags: c#

Полностью ли помещается лонг в даубл? И там и там по 8 байт, но просто может быть есть какие то нюансы о которых мне не известно?

Может ли быть так что после конвертации лонга в даубл обратная конвертация будет неверной?

## Дополнено

Задача, созранение дат в формате Double. Я перевожу DateTime.Ticks в формат double и сохраняю его с массивом данных которым он соответствует в файле ввиде битов.
Что вроде такого :
Дата
Значение
значение
Дата
Значение
значение
Дата
Значение
значение
Дата
Значение
значение

Возможен ли тут сбой ? Дата не превышает текущей (ну увеличивается ежедневно) и не менее 2000 года

Comment: у Double точность ~15-17 знаков. У long максимальное значение - 9*10^18.  При конвертации будут потери.

Comment: Вы скажите, какую конкретную задачу решаете. Возможно, стоит посмотреть в сторону `decimal` или `BigIntiger`.

Comment: @PashaPash, не в знаках её измерять нужно, а в битах)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Дополнил вопрос

Comment: @JamesBondCaesar, дополнил ответ.

Comment: И ещё раз обновил ответ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Полностью ли помещается лонг в даубл? И там и там по 8 байт

Нет. Очевидно, что при одинаковом размере это невозможно. Есть одинаковый объём, причём `long` хранит числа без избыточности (т. е. каждой комбинации бит соответствует уникальное число). Не увеличивая объёма сохранить новые значения (все дробные, да даже просто ещё одно дробное, например, 0.5) невозможно. А поскольку известно, что double может хранить значения за пределами long, становится понятно, что он неспособен хранить все значения типа `long`.

> Может ли быть так что после конвертации лонга в даубл обратная конвертация будет неверной?

`double` может хранить точно целые числа до 2**53 (по модулю) включительно. В этом диапазоне конвертация будет точной и вычисления, работающие только с целыми числами, тоже. Как только за этот диапазон выходишь, младшие биты начинают теряться.

https://ideone.com/HSBgd5

```
using System;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    long x = (1L << 53) + 17;
    double y = x;
    long z = (long)y;
    
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    Console.WriteLine("{0:0}, last digits: {1}", y, y % 10000.0);
    Console.WriteLine(z);
  }
}
```

```
9007199254741009
9007199254741010, last digits: 1008
9007199254741008
```

То, что вместо `08` выводится `10` - это косяк вывода, реально хранится значение с восьмёркой.

> Я перевожу DateTime.Ticks в формат double

И данные теряются. Мог бы и сам проверить: https://ideone.com/knqMBs

```
using System;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.MinValue.Ticks);
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks);
    Console.WriteLine(1L << 53);
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(1L << 53));
  }
}
```

```
0
3155378975999999999
9007199254740992
637570616761754540
7/17/0029 11:58:45 PM
```

Точный диапазон double покрывает годы до 0029 невключительно (не 2029, а 00 - примерно 2000 лет назад). Для современных дат ты теряешь около 7 последних бит.

Или так: https://ideone.com/UvZfic

```
using System;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    var date0 = DateTime.Now;
    double dbl = date0.Ticks;
    var date1 = new DateTime((long)dbl);
    
    Console.WriteLine(date0.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff"));
    Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff"));

    Console.WriteLine(date0.Ticks);
    Console.WriteLine(date1.Ticks);
  }
}
```

```
2021_05_19 23:10:44.7633170
2021_05_19 23:10:44.7633152
637570626447633170
637570626447633152
```

Кстати, интересный факт: VB6, VBA и MS Office используют double для хранения дат, но они делают это иначе: целая часть - это количество дней от начала отсчёта, а дробная - время. Естественно, точность всё равно страдает по сравнению с тиками.

---

Интересные материалы по теме:

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/734615/178988
- [Потерялся 1 бит в long double](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/734770/178988)
- [Отображение числа 9223372036854775807](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/690856/178988)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/1421520/4928642

Comment: А лимит равен именно 2^53 потому, что формат IEEE 754 использует 52 бита под мантиссу (плюс неявная старшая единица).

Comment: Потому что не вижу в своём ответе ничего того, чего нет в вашем. Но если вы что-то хотите оттуда взять, чтобы дополнить этот ответ, я только за.

Comment: @aepot, ну у тебя ссылки совсем другие, к тому же ты первым написал)

Comment: Ничего страшного, заберите к себе их, если считаете полезными. У вас отличный ответ. Репу не жалко, ее у меня и так некуда девать.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(long i = long.MaxValue; i > long.MaxValue-100000; i-=2000)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"long = {i}\r\ndouble={((double)i).ToString("F3")}\r\n");
}
```

Нужна ли вам такая погрешность?