# Определение машинного эпсилон для типов double и float в С++

Tags: c++, float, типы, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Поставлена стандартная для новичка задача - определить *машинный эпсилон* для типов данных float и double на C++. Код для float выглядит так:

```
    i = 0;
    epsilon_f = 1.0;
    

    while(1.0 + epsilon_f > 1.0)
    {
        epsilon_f = epsilon_f / 2.0;
        i++;
    }
    cout << "Machine epsilon for float type: " << epsilon_f << endl;
    cout << "The amount of iterations for float type: " << i << endl;
```

Вывод программы следующий:

> Machine epsilon for float type: 1.11022e-16

> The amount of iterations for float type: 53

Но насколько я понимаю, такое значение машинного эпсилон у типа double (только в два раза больше, так как цикл while сработал лишний раз). В чём ошибка? Как исправить код? Может, неправильная работа с типами данных?

Comment: А вы не пробовали писать `1.0f`?

Comment: @Harry, а зачем? Там же тип переменной важен, а не константы.

Comment: Я делал вот так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/734770/178988.

Comment: @Harry, а, понял, сложение в условии получается с приведением.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Просто вы работаете с `double` — так как все литералы именно `double` по умолчанию.

Сравните вывод в этом случае:

```
int i = 0;
float epsilon_f = 1.0;


while(1.0f + epsilon_f > 1.0f)
{
    epsilon_f = epsilon_f / 2.0f;
    i++;
}
cout << "Machine epsilon for float type: " << epsilon_f << endl;
cout << "The amount of iterations for float type: " << i << endl;
```

Здесь мы явно указываем тип `float`.

См. https://ideone.com/luOC4F

Comment: `1.0f + epsilon_f` - но ведь компилятор не обязан это считать в рамках float? Не будет та же проблема как с false в `sin(x)==sin(x)`? Может в какой-нибудь `volatile float` явно кастить?

Comment: @Qwertiy, в процессе выбора всегда вызывается функция,  чьи аргументы  наилучшим образом соответствуют. Вряд ли  результат float + float будет преобразован, чтобы сравнивать с тем же типом

Comment: @Qwertiy Да вроде нет, потому что тут promotion не нужен...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, ну уж нет. Я сломал оба результата добавив компилятору флаг `-mfpmath=387`: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bxrToYz81. Теперь оба результата `5.42101e-20, 64`, хотя были `5.96046e-08, 24` и `1.11022e-16, 53`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, `1.0f + epsilon_f - но ведь компилятор не обязан это считать в рамках float?` Вы правы. Хоть результат данного выражения имеет тип `float`, но стандарт языка явным образом разрешает результату выражения иметь большую точность и диапазон, чем таковые у типа `float`: [expr.pre/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.pre#6): `The values of the floating-point operands and the results of floating-point expressions may be represented in greater precision and range than that required by the type; the types are not changed thereby.`

Comment: @Qwertiy, `Может в какой-нибудь volatile float явно кастить?` С точки зрения стандарта явное приведение типа и операция присваивания должны обрезать расширенные точность и диапазон. Но на практике компиляторы не всегда выполняют это требование. Если нужна уверенность, что вычисления будут производиться на самом деле во `float`, а не в каком-нибудь `double`, то нужно тщательно изучать документацию на конкретный компилятор.

Comment: @wololo, ну присваивание в переменную volatile float и чтение из неё обязаны всё порезать. Хотя, если по стандарту достаточно просто каста, можно попробовать и его.

Comment: @Qwertiy, согласно примечанию 46 к 7.1 (6), должно хватать, либо приведения, либо присвоения  к float, но `gcc -mfpmath=387 -O0` правильно реализует только присвоение, а для того что бы работало приведение требуется `gcc -mfpmath=387 -O1`, что забавно. Кроме того **глючность компиляторов беспредельна же** для `gcc -mfpmath=387 -O1 -ffast-math` таки требуется `volatile`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, P.S. с точки зрения производительности, вероятно, лучше использовать `std::atomic<float>` (`_Atomic(float)` C17/C++23) с ослабленным доступом.

Comment: @Qwertiy См. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16325515/9123401

Answer (score 5):

Не совсем ответ, а скорее заметка по вопросу точности.

Объявляя вещественные переменные как `float` (32 бит) или `double` (64 бит), многие почему-то забывают (или не все знают), что процессор (сопроцессор) всегда преобразует эти переменные в 80-битный тип `long double` - это происходит автоматически при их загрузке в 80-битные регистры стека сопроцессора (при выгрузке значений в память, происходит обратное преобразование). И все вычисления производятся над 80-битными вещественными значениями. Реальная же точность операций задаётся определёнными битами управляющего слова в регистре `CWR`. По умолчанию эта точность соответствует типу `double`. А значит, даже если исходные значения хранятся во `float`, процессор всё равно обрабатывает их в регистрах с точностью `double`. По-этому, чтобы по-настоящему ограничить точность вычислений в 32 бита, необходимо соответствующим образом изменить значение регистра `CWR`, либо в ассемблере (с помощью инструкций `fstcw`, `fldcw`), либо вызвав библиотечную функцию `_control87()`.

Так как же в этом случае отработает следующий код? Ведь вычисления всё равно имеют точность 64 бит!

```
    int i = 0;
    float epsilon_f = 1.0;

    while(1.0f + epsilon_f > 1.0f)
    {
        epsilon_f = epsilon_f / 2.0f;
        i++;
    }
```

Я откомпилировал его, и отработал он, как ни странно, корректно:

```
Machine epsilon for float type: 5.96046e-008
The amount of iterations for float type: 24
```

В чём же дело? Ответ - в дизассемблере:

```
.text:004A62E6                 xor     eax, eax        ; int i = 0
.text:004A62E8                 fld1                    ; epsilon_f = 1.0
.text:004A62EA                 lea     esi, [esi+0]
.text:004A62F0
.text:004A62F0 Do_While:                               ; CODE XREF: _main+2A↓j
.text:004A62F0                 inc     eax             ; do {i++
.text:004A62F1                 fmul    ds:const_0_5f   ; epsilon_f = epsilon_f*0.5
.text:004A62F7                 cmp     eax, 24         ; } while (i!=24)
.text:004A62FA                 jnz     short Do_While  ; do {i++
```

Короче, компилятор оказался настолько умён, что понял, что от него требуется и просто заменил цикл `while(1.0f + epsilon_f > 1.0f) {...}` на цикл:

```
    do
    {
        i++;
        epsilon_f = epsilon_f*0.5;
    } while (i!=24);
```

Вот такие чудеса оптимизации.

Comment: «Не совсем ответ», так и да, если мы можем использовать `_control87()`, то нам и точность одинарной арифметики тоже известна, и можем сразу константу вернуть.

Comment: @Serge3leo ну так-то нам и цикл не нужен. Машинный эпсилон относительно единицы равен 2 в степени минус разрядность мантиссы. Так, для `float` разрядность мантиссы равна 24 битам, отсюда получаем `epsilon_f  = pow(2.0, -24)` = 5.96046e-008. Разрядность мантиссы `double` равна 53, следовательно `epsilon_d = pow(2.0, -53)` = 1.1102e-16.

Comment: @ LShadow77 , зачем нам `pow`? Нам `pow` не нужен, у нас `FLT_EPSILON` и `DBL_EPSILON` есть, а для особых ценителей `std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon()`

Comment: @Serge3leo, я собственно не про pow(), а про то, как вообще эти величины получаются.