# Как представить float в виде integer без потери информации?

Tags: python, python-3.x, преобразование-типов, информация

Есть задача преобразования `float` значений в значения типа `int` (одно `float` значение в одно `int` значение) без потери информации, т.е., чтобы потом можно было выполнить обратное преобразование. Как это можно реализовать?

### Важно

Надо, чтобы при таком преобразовании сохранялся порядок и сумма,
т.е. для любых `a, b: float` должно выполняться:

```
to_float(to_int(a) + to_int(b)) == a + b

to_int(a) < to_int(b) при a < b и т.д.
```

Нашёл на англоязычном SO [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48232399/10941639), где побитово представляется структура `float` значений, но не представляю, как её можно применить для своей задачи.

Примечание: `NaN` и `inf` в моей задаче преобразовывать не надо.

---

#### Попытки решения

Изначально на ум пришла сериализация с помощью `pickle.dumps`, а затем получение `int` из этих байт, но это совсем не рациональное решение и оно совершенно не удовлетворяет требованиям.

Были попытки реализовать это через байтовые представления чисел ([ответ Qwertiy♦](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1192370/324059)), в таком варианте не сохраняется сумма.

Comment: Можно использовать Fraction: `fractions.Fraction(0.1+0.2)` => `Fraction(1351079888211149, 4503599627370496)`
`

Comment: @vp_arth Да я ему предлагал. Говорит два инта не хочу, хочу один! ))

Comment: @vp_arth Ок. Можно. А как потом эти числитель и знаменатель хранить в одном `int` значении? И как их потом друг от друга отделять после сложения, например?

Comment: Тогда так: `((0.1+0.2)*1e32).as_integer_ratio()[0] / 1e32 == (0.1+0.2)` 32 взял «от балды», не в курсе, сколько там точности)

Comment: @vp_arth В питоне числа с плавающей точкой являются `double` (64 бит), вроде как. Идею Вашу понял, сейчас попробую потестировать.

Comment: @vp_arth Сумма сохраняется с точностью до `sys.float_info.epsilon` (не точно, но уже хоть что-то), но порядок не сохраняется :/ Например, для чисел `1.043380078e-314, 2.0142355855e-314` (в преобразовании `e32` заменил на `e64`).

Comment: Лучше на `(1<<64)`. Ну да, если вам весь диапазон нужен, такой фокус не пройдёт, знаменатель слишком большой)

Comment: Если выполнять нужное условие по сравнению, целые числа должны содержать более 600 разрядов) Думаю, тут нужно не выдумывать велосипед, а настраивать Decimal: `float(Decimal.from_float(1.23e-312))`. Хотя, вам нужен именно int...

Comment: @vp_arth *>если вам весь диапазон нужен, такой фокус не пройдёт, знаменатель слишком большой)* - А для какого диапазона применимо Ваше решение?

Comment: Ну, это же вы сами можете выбрать. Например, для сдвига в (1<<128) вы получите диапазон около 1e-20..1e+260. Больше сдвиг - доступны более мелкие, недоступны(обращаются в бесконечность) более крупные.

Comment: @vp_arth Оформите ответом? С подробным описанием, как и почему это работает

Comment: Оформил. Но на самом деле, 2й ответ @Qwertiy — фактически то же самое, что бы он ни имел в виду под «постепенным умножением» =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое — просто умножать и делить на достаточно большой коэффициент, чтобы покрыть необходимый диапазон значений.

```
ratio = (1 << 156)

def to_int(f):
    """ Если точности недостаточно, может вернуть 0 или бросить OverflowError при конвертации получившейся при умножении бесконечности
    """
    return int(f * ratio)

def to_float(d):
    return d / ratio


def to_int_2(f):
    r = (f * ratio).as_integer_ratio()
    assert r[1] == 1, 'Not enough precision'
    return r[0]
```

Немного утверждений:

```
# На некоторых ratio мы таки будем получать получать ровно 0.3 при сложении, так что тут поведение нестабильно    
assert to_float(to_int(0.1) + to_int(0.2)) == 0.1 + 0.2

assert to_float(to_int(-1.03e-30) + to_int(-2.04e-31)) == (-1.234e-30)
assert to_float(to_int(-1.03e+130) + to_int(-2.04e+129)) == (-1.234e+130)


assert to_int(1e-300) == 0
try:
    print(to_int(1e+300))
except OverflowError as e:
    assert str(e) == 'cannot convert float infinity to integer'

# to_int_2
assert to_float(to_int_2(0.1) + to_int_2(0.2)) == 0.1 + 0.2
assert to_float(to_int_2(-1.03e-30) + to_int_2(-2.04e-31)) == (-1.234e-30)
assert to_float(to_int_2(-1.03e+130) + to_int_2(-2.04e+129)) == (-1.234e+130)
try:
    to_int_2(1e-300) == 0
except AssertionError as e:
    assert str(e) == 'Not enough precision'
try:
    print(to_int_2(1e+300))
except OverflowError as e:
    assert str(e) == 'cannot convert Infinity to integer ratio'
```

Сейчас прихожу к выводу, что as_integer_ratio не нужен, достаточно проверки `res == 0 and f != 0` в to_int.

Comment: А как это работает? Почему при умножении на степень двойки знаменатель становится `1`?

Comment: Потому что все числа с плавающей запятой рациональны. Состав коэффициента(степень двойки, десятки да хоть тройки) не принципиален. Главное — быть достаточно большим, чтобы исчерпать(перенести в целую часть) все значащие цифры.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> to_float(to_int(a) + to_int(b)) == a + b
> to_int(a) < to_int(b) при a < b и т.д.
> ```

Я вспомнил, что в питоне int'ы бесконечные.
У [double](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) есть 11 бит на степень, значит при умножении на 2**(2**12) получится целое число, которое можно положить в int. Только умножать надо по мере перевода, а не дробное число - иначе произойдёт переполнение.

Comment: Что значит "по мере перевода"? Не могли бы Вы, пожалуйста, приложить пример?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, должно быть какое-то сходство с этим: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/734615/178988.

Answer (score 1):

Надо просто двоичное представление float'а переинтерпретировать в целое число.

На основе https://stackoverflow.com/a/14431225/4928642

```
import struct

def floatBits(f):
  s = struct.pack('>f', f)
  return struct.unpack('>l', s)[0]
```

На основе https://stackoverflow.com/a/58362843/4928642

```
import ctypes

def floatBits(x):
  f = ctypes.c_float(x)
  return ctypes.c_int.from_address(ctypes.addressof(f)).value
```

> Данное преобразование не сохраняет сумму :(
>
> ```
> lhs = random.getrandbits(30)
> rhs = random.getrandbits(30)
> assert int_to_float(lhs) + int_to_float(rhs) == int_to_float(lhs + rhs)
> ```

И не должно. И вообще не получится сделать так, чтобы сохраняло.

Comment: Спасибо! Именно это-то подобное я и считал рациональным решением, но не знал, как в питоне из `float` получить его битовое представление. Осталось лишь удостовериться, что сохраняются операции.

Comment: Данное преобразование не сохраняет сумму :( `lhs = random.getrandbits(30); rhs = random.getrandbits(30); assert int_to_float(lhs) + int_to_float(rhs) == int_to_float(lhs + rhs)`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, а с какой стати оно должно её сохранять?

Answer (score 1):

А зря вы не хотите в двух целых числах хранить. Для этого в Python даже специальная библиотека есть. Которая может представить любое `float` число в виде точной дроби и работать с такими числами можно совершенно естественным образом:

```
from fractions import Fraction

print(Fraction(0.123456789))
# 8895999182988127/72057594037927936

print(float(Fraction(8895999182988127, 72057594037927936)))
# 0.123456789
```

Comment: Тут не "я хочу", а надо :) Вместо библиотеки тогда уж можно использовать просто `float.as_integer_ratio`.

Answer (score 0):

**первый способ**

хорошо то, что в программировании не бывает иррациональных чисел :), а значит любой float - рациональный

поэтому его можно представить в виде дроби - т.е. 2х чисел `int`

учитывая, что в питоне целочисленные значения не ограничены длинной, то в одном числе может быть 2 числа

например `0,5` - это `[5][10]`,

можно реализовать такое хранение

**второй способ**

**float** очень легко переводятся в **fixed** - числа с фиксированной точкой - например если считать что первые n знаков - целая часть, а вторые m знаков - дробная часть, то

сложение и вычитание чисел будет ровно таким же как и у float или int

сравнение чисел будет ровно таким же как и у float или int

умножение будет чуть другим -

```
(a * b) >> m
```

перевод float в fixed:

```
fixed_value = 2**m * float_value
```

обратно соответственно

```
float_value = fixed_value / 2**m
```

Comment: Первый способ очень близок к правде, но хранить надо одним целым числом. Если в одном числе "хранить" 2 числа для дроби, то как их потом друг от друга отделять? И не будет ли потом проблемой их друг от друга отделить после сложения? По второму способу не понимаю, что значит `первые n знаков`. Первые n знаков где?

Comment: Что с NaN и бесконечностями?

Comment: @Qwertiy NaN и бесконечностей в моём кейсе нет.

Answer (score 0):

2 метода:

Из `float` в `long`

```
def floatToRawLongBits(f):
    s = struct.pack('=f', f)
    return struct.unpack('=l', s)[0]
```

Обратно из `long` в `float`

```
def longToRawFloatBits(l):
    s = struct.pack('=l', l)
    return struct.unpack('=f', s)[0]
```

Просьба сильно не бить, ногами, пока не силен в Python

В Java есть метод `Float.floatToRawIntBits()`, который битовое определение IEEE 754, представляет в виде битов целого числа. По его аналогии [есть решение](https://qna.habr.com/q/119959)

Comment: У меня почти то же самjе. А в чём разница между `>` и `=`?